# Debouncing rx based on value

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I'm trying to show a popup if my client is disconnected (false) for more than 10 seconds. However, I'm also dismissing the popup when the connection is regained (true). I need the popup to be dismissed instantly if true.

I think what I need to do is debounce based on value (false) but i'm not sure.

```
mConnectionObservable
.distinctUntilChanged()
.debounce(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.subscribe(online -> {
    if (online) {
        //Dismiss popup
    } else {
        //Show popup about internet connection
    }
});
```

Comment: Does you `mConnectionObservable` continuously emit the connection state periodically or does it only emit when the connection state changes?

Comment: Emits only on a change. It's Firebase's listener on '.info/connected'

Answer (score 11):

You can try

```
mConnectionObservable.debounce(item -> (item? Observable.empty() : Observable.timer(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                     .distinctUntilChanged()
```

This dynamically changes the debounce period so that a true value is always emitted but a false value with have the 10 second debounce.

Comment: Interesting! And does this also solve the problem of old false values arriving after more recent true's?

Comment: It's a single stream so I don't think it would be possible to get older emitted values arriving after newer ones.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks @JohnWowUs !

Comment: rx creativity at its finest.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if you split the stream in two (one for true, one for false) and debounce only the false stream.

```
mConnectionObservable
.distinctUntilChanged()
.publish(items -> items.filter(item -> item == true)
    .mergeWith(items.filter(item -> item == false).debounce(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(online -> {
    if (online) {
        //Dismiss popup
    } else {
        //Show popup about internet connection
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @LordRaydenMK Any idea if the debounce could cause an old false to arrive after a more recent true? Or will that debounce always check for the latest value?
I'll give it a test 

Comment: `concatWith` might be better if you want to preserve order.

Comment: I'm getting crashes since adding the publish(), It's probably the thread i'm observing/subscribing on in Android? ```Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()```

Comment: debounce changes the scheduler. Add `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` before working with the UI (dialog)

Comment: Thanks @LordRaydenMK It's still crashing when I add the observeOn before the .distinctUntilChanged() should it be added within the publish() also?

Comment: Thanks LordRaydenMK and @JohnWowUs. I've gotten it working with .mergeWith(). .concatWith() was only giving me the first result, but nothing after that. With the current answer, could an old false possibly come after a more recent true? I wonder should I do another connection check in my .subscribe() if online = false to avoid timing issues?

Comment: @AlanHaverty `concatWith` doesn't work because it waits for the first stream to complete before starting the second one, and the first one never completes. I think the problem you describe exists... if I figure out a solution I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks @LordRaydenMK Appreciate it 

Comment: LordRaydenMK I think @JohnWowUs answer solves my question without the lagging debounce issue. Appreciate the answers/comments!